# CI Active record, Select record from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two table. First is `product` in which Admin will add the Products and another is `product_detail` in which vendors will add the detail. Multiple vendors can add same product with the product detail like selling price, offer price etc.

"I want to select products from `products` table and want to select product detail from `product_detail` table but only one row of product detail which has less  selling price".

So i want to use CI active records to get the final output as product list with its detail.

Comment: you want only the lowest price product?

Comment: price=min(price) used in where condition

Comment: all understandable rather this *but only one row of product detail which has less selling price".* as well please add expected result/example for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Take this for example :

```
Create table #Product(id int, name varchar(100));
Create table #Product_detail(id int, product_id int, detail varchar(100));

insert into #Product values
(1,'Item1'),
(2,'Item2')


insert into #Product_detail values
(1,1,20),
(2,1,10),
(3,1,40),
(4,2,70),
(5,2,50)
```

this is your basic query:

```
select 
a.*, b.price
from 
 #product a inner join
 (select product_id, min(price) price
  from #product_detail
  group by product_id
 ) b
on a.id = b.product_id
```

In CI, try to do something like this:

```
$var = $this->db->query("select a.*, b.price from #product a 
                         inner join
                        (select product_id, min(price) price
                         from #product_detail
                         group by product_id
                         ) b
                        on a.id = b.product_id")->result_array();
```

sample output :

```
id          name   price
----------- ------ -----------
1           Item1  10
2           Item2  50
```

Answer (score 0):

You first should make getters and setters in your model and using CI active record + pdo It'as more safe from my point of view.

Best regards.